# Issue transferring files with Robocopy (Xcopy works)

Tags: batch-file

For the last year I have been transferring files stored on a remote pc's external hdd to our Windows 2008 server using a batch script (using robocopy). Everything has been working with no issue up until a few weeks ago. Now when I check the log file I get this error message:

```
ERROR 64 (0x000000040) Scanning Source Directory \\1195-VISION\1195 Image HD\1195_Images\
The specified network name is no longer available
```

No files get transferred, the script retries but is never successful. I have two other identical scripts (pointed to a different source) which are still working with no issue.

When I wrote script using XCOPY the files started to transfer with no issues.

Below is one of the scripts:

```
SET SOURCE="\\1195-VISION\1195 Image HD\1195_Images"
SET DEST="D:\Incoming_Pictures"
robocopy %SOURCE% %DEST% /MOV /S /MON:1 /W:5 /LOG:"D:\Incoming_Pictures\1195_LOG_FILE"
```

Any insight why robocopy stopped working would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I'm still able to connect and manually drag files from the external HDD. So the path still exits. Furthermore, if the path did not exist xcopy would not work.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear - "The specified network name is no longer available". It would appear that you no longer have `\\1195-VISION` available, or the `1195 Image HD` that was on it. So check the remote pc's external hdd and see what's changed on it (which we can't do for you from here).

Comment: I'm still able to connect and manually drag files from the external HDD. So the path still exits. Furthermore, if the path did not exist xcopy would not work (which I believe I mentioned above)

Comment: There is some part of the path that isn't available as named, as the error message clearly says. I can't confirm that your XCOPY effort worked, because a) you didn't include the specific xcopy command so I can confirm that the provided path information is identical, and b) because I can't access the hardware to confirm that the locations are or are not there. "Manually connecting" doesn't mean "use the same exact names for the devices and complete the copy". I'm not sure how you expect us to identify why robocopy would not be able to locate a network path to a device on a network we can't see.

Comment: Also note that it could be either side of the equation (source or destination) that isn't available.